# Confusion regarding term "offset"?

Tags: terminology, dc-offset, offset

I am confused regarding term "offset".

What is its meaning in context of function generator and oscilloscope?

I have tried to google, but I get results in context of op amp and some results show it is almost same thing like DC shift.

But what happens in context of function generator and oscilloscope when we use the term "offset"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Offset** is a DC bias added to (or part of) a signal.

Example:

- 1V peak-to-peak AC sine wave signal, with an average voltage of +2V is said to have a +2V *offset*.

**A function generator** can add an offset (DC bias) to generate such a signal. For example, to make a 5V square wave for TTL logic, you'll select a 2.5V amplitude (5V peak-to-peak) square wave and 2.5V offset, to get a signal that swings from 0V to 5V.

**An oscilloscope** can add (or subtract) an offset to an input so that the 'interesting' part of the signal is front-and-center. A good example is viewing variation on a DC power supply. For a 5V supply, you'd add a negative offset (-5V) to the probe input to view the variations (noise, ripple, etc.) in the middle of the scope.

(Why not just use AC coupling? The AC coupling high-pass effect blocks longer-term variations, such as line and load regulation.)